# WM_GETTEXT usage

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, sendmessage

I'm trying to get the status of a text field in my application. But I don't get it to work. I'm using "SendMessage" to get "WM_GETTEXT", I save the content to a char *.

I output the char * to a file, but I only get "D" back. This is what I have now:

```
LRESULT result;
char * output = (char*)malloc(1024);

result = SendMessage(hwnd,WM_GETTEXT,1024,(LPARAM)output);

ofstream file("test.txt");
file <<  *output;
file.close();

delete [] output;
```

Comment: @SophiaLife you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Aside: match `malloc` with `free` and `new` with `delete`. Don't mix'n'match.

Answer (score 5):

Pointers concepts

file <<  *output; will print the first element of the string array

file << output; print the entire string

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work. I still get "D" as output. ( file << output; )

Answer (score 0):

C# code:

```
public const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0xD;
const int bufferSize = 10000;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);
SendMessageGetText(handle, WM_GETTEXT, new UIntPtr(bufferSize), sb);

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Working properly to me!

Answer (score 0):

Sophia's answer is correct. However, the default now for a Visual Studio project is to create a Unicode project. You will only get the first letter if your project is Unicode and not MBCS.

Have you examined the buffer returned from WM_GETTEXT to verify it has the entire string?

If not, try declaring your output variable as TCHAR* (to be generic) or as a wchar_t* and see what results you get in the buffer.

p.s. It is bad form to allocate memory with malloc and release it with delete.  You should either use malloc/free pairs or new/delete pairs. Even safer way to allocate a char buffer is to use std::string or use std::wstring for a wide string.

p.p.s Try making sure your project settings are for a Multibyte project and not Unicode project. Then everything in Sophia's answer will work.

One more thing... Just use GetWindowText() API instead of the SendMessage stuff. That's why it is there so you don't have to go through the rigmarole of casting a pointer to a LPARAM or WPARAM.  It's more typesafe and will give you a compile time error (better than runtime errors) if your types don't match up--especially with Unicode/MBCS and wchar_t/char.